# highlight a specific row "person", a `TextArea` next to the table will show some text about that person "row".., and it's different from each row..!

Tags: java, swing, jtable, selecteditem, defaulttablemodel

I made `Jtable` using `TableModel` witch view data Persons(name, age..ect) from `Arraylist`, What I need is when I highlight a specific row "person", a `TextArea` next to the table will show some text about that person "row".., and it's different from each row..!

I made `jTable1MousePressed` and i tried some code but I can't figuer out how to select exact row.. with this `getSelectedRow()` i couldn't specify what row i pressed..! i read about `ListSelectionListener` but I didn't understand it !

Comment: sorry guys about the question title .. i post before shot it out '_'  , i can't change it just yet coz of low reputation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a mouse listener to you table and get the col/row. Obviously, change values as needed to fit your purpose. I use this to determine the row and col clicked as well as where to display a popup menu.

```
table.addMouseListener(getMouseAdapter());
```

And the code for the MouseAdaptor:

```
public MouseAdapter getMouseAdapter() {
        return new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                app.setLastClickedComponent(ADVTableOperations.this);
                rowClicked = rowAtPoint(e.getPoint());
                colClicked = columnAtPoint(e.getPoint());
                if (e.isPopupTrigger() && isPopUpEnabled()) {
                    popUpMenu.show(e.getComponent(), e.getX(), e.getY());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                app.setLastClickedComponent(ADVTableOperations.this);
                rowClicked = rowAtPoint(e.getPoint());
                colClicked = columnAtPoint(e.getPoint());

                if (e.isPopupTrigger() && isPopUpEnabled()) {
                    popUpMenu.show(e.getComponent(), e.getX(), e.getY());
                }
            }
        };
    }
```

Comment: ok .. so can't i use just one event like jTable1MousePressed ?

Comment: Yes, you can use a MousePressed event. You can use which ever one youd like.

Comment: Also, are you using a JScrollPane?

Comment: i'm using a builder using NetBeans ..i can't put methods inside
     `private void jTable1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) { `                                    
     `//what should i put here ?`
     `}`

Comment: You can use the custom code section of the GUI builder, or better yet, you can certainly call a method from the listener.